# Sign Application in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-build

I am a web developer and I recently decided to learn how to build apps in Android, using the first-party IDE Android Studio.

I spent a few days designing a tutorial app, which I managed to run in an emulator, and then I've been programming and designing the layout for my own app.

However, I've been running into a problem when I try to test the app.

```
Waiting for device. 
Target device: emulator-5556 (Nexus7_2) Uploading file
local path: C:\{file_path}\{app}-release-unsigned.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/{app_name}
Installing {app_name}
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/{app_name}"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/{app_name}
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

By looking up this error online, I've figured out that I need to sign my app, but I haven't figure out a way for this to work in the case of Android Studio. Modifying the ant build.xml file doesn't work and other methods of signing don't seem to work either.

There is an option to Generate a Signed APK, and I exported an app that was signed. However, I cannot seem to put that apk into my emulator.

If there is anyone more knowledgeable about how to use Android Studio, I would appreciate the assistance in how to sign my apk with the software. Thanks.

**Output from Tutorial App**

I copied all the code that wasn't included with the new project. This application does work in the emulator.

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: emulator-5556 (Nexus7_2)
Uploading file
local path: C:\{file_path}\QuoteReader-debug-unaligned.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/{app_name}
Installing {app_name}
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/{app_name}"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/{app_name}
Success
Launching application: ...quotereader.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "...quotereader.MainActivity" -a     android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=    [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp={app_name}/.MainActivity }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you delete the app on your phone then it should work when you run it again.